# How do I convert a ListView SelectedItem into an IObservable?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, system.reactive, reactive-programming

This may be a remedial question, but my research is spinning me in circles right now (especially as a Java developer) and looking at several different Rx wrapper libraries. All I want is to take a `ListView<MusicNote>.SelectedItem` and wrap it into an `IObservable`, emitting a stream of the current single selected value. What is the easiest means to do this? Should I use the ReactiveProperty, Rx-XAML, or some library? Or is there an easy built-in way to do this with Rx.NET? I would prefer to not use a traditional event method stub that VS generates. Although I could push values in that, it feels messy and is not the paradigm I want.

`this.keySelector.SelectedItem // turn this ListView's SelectedItem into an IObservable`

Comment: This sounds like a cool undertaking. My personal route would be to assign listeners to the SelectedIndexChanged event. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Please spend some time to write some code that provides a basic example of what you're trying to do so that we have something to work from. You shouldn't expect us to write the code from scratch. Make your question easy to answer and you'll increase the chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: I'll add some details as I struggle through it @Gandalf458 Thanks, I'm looking at the link right now. Yeah this is a Windows 8.1 app I'm excited about. It's a guitar scale app driven by a music theory algorithm. It's an ideal project to use reactive programming because there is a lot of state management reacting to user input (scale changes, key changes, chord changes, and tuning changes). Everything needs to recalculate reactively as those four variables are modified.

Comment: Got it all done. Answer is below. Thanks for your help guys. I was able to build something awesome after struggling through it. Here's a demo of what I built, and it is almost 100% reactive https://goo.gl/HTF3zd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help guys. This is ultimately what I ended up doing. Although I didn't want to do it this way initially it seems to be the simplest. And here is the final product of my work  https://goo.gl/HTF3zd

```
        private readonly ReplaySubject<TuningChangeEvent> tuningChange = new ReplaySubject<TuningChangeEvent>();


        private void OneTuner_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e) {
           tuningChange.OnNext(TuningChangeEvent.tune(1,Convert.ToInt32(OneTuner.Value)));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it in Rx.Net is the following:

```
var whenSelectionChange = Observable.FromEventPattern(h => listView.SelectedIndexChanged += h, 
                                                      h => listView.SelectedIndexChanged -= h)
                                    .Select(_ => listView.SelectedItem);
```

Basically, FromEventPattern() generates an observable sequence from the SelectedIndexChanged events triggered by your ListView. The Select() will be called each time an event is triggered, so you can get the selected index from your list and return it. The whenSelectionChange will be an `IObservable<int>` where each added element is the new selected index.

I have never used it, but you can take a look at http://reactiveui.net/ It's a MVVM framework that seems to integrate well with RX.Net and it is supported on all mobile platforms.